# PHP Get user input without user having to press return key

Tags: php, command-line-interface, stdin

Hi I am using PHP in CLI mode (Command Line Interface)

I would like to get the key the user types and immediately have it submitted to the program without the user having to press the return key(Enter Key)
So for example's sake I'ld like it to print the letter the user types immediately. So if the user types an "a" it immediately shows an "a" in the command prompt. How would I do this?

```
 do {  
     $selection = fgetc(STDIN);  
 fwrite(STOUT, "$selection");
 } while ( trim($selection) == '' );
```

Comment: just curious whats the person of the command line with php i have seen this done by some guy on youtube is it a form of preference?

Comment: Usually I use php to do web development but this is more of a personal project and I don't need to fiddle around with html (not that it is a real problem) I just want this task to feel like it's running like a real program instead of calling up an html page.

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to disable input buffering:

http://www.mail-archive.com/php-general@lists.php.net/msg151195.html seems to work:

```
exec("stty -icanon min 0 time 0");
```

Some other suggestions are here: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34972 but `stream_set_blocking(STDIN, false);` for example has no effect

Answer (score 1):

Either disable buffering on stdin or use ncurses instead.

Comment: how do you disable buffering?

Comment: That I'm not sure of, mostly because I've never had to do it (I usually use ncurses or readline for user input).