# Reading a command line input in PHP

Tags: php, input, command-line-interface, space, enter

I want to read command line input in PHP.
I used  fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $numbers_arr[$i]);
But this takes input when enter key is pressed. How can i read input when the space key is pressed.

The input format will be in two lines like below

5 2

1 2 3 4 5

first line consists of two inputs and second line consists of no.of elements entered as first number in first line.

please let me know how to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254415/php-get-user-input-without-user-having-to-press-return-key

Comment: Definitely not how you're doing it. Stop trying to write C code in Python.

Comment: If you want an interactive CLI program, PHP is *not* the tool to use unless your extending a considerable existing codebase (IE - admin tools for a website).  You're trying to stick a square hammer into a round hole.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how PHP works on the command line. You'll need to find a different way to structure your input.